# sequelize migration throws ERROR: function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I enabled `uuid` extension with `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`

Then ran same query generated by sequelize for migration and it worked,

```
create table if not exists "MY_SCHEMA"."Users" ("id" UUID not null default uuid_generate_v4() ,
"phone" VARCHAR(10) not null,
"password" VARCHAR(50) not null,
"isDeleted" BOOLEAN default false,
"role" "MY_SCHEMA"."enum_Users_role" default 'Student',
"createdAt" TIMESTAMP with TIME zone not null,
"updatedAt" TIMESTAMP with TIME zone not null,
primary key ("id"));
```

But, sequelize throws below error,

```
ERROR: function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
```

Here is the migration file,

```
const SCHEMA = 'MY_SCHEMA';
const TABLE_WITH_SCHEMA = { tableName: 'Users', schema: SCHEMA };

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable(TABLE_WITH_SCHEMA, {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()'),
        type: Sequelize.UUID
      },
      phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(10),
        allowNull: false
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
      },
      isDeleted: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
      },
      role: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('Admin', 'Teacher', 'Student'),
        defaultValue: 'Student'
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
    await queryInterface.addIndex(TABLE_WITH_SCHEMA, ['phone'], {
      indicesType: 'UNIQUE'
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable(TABLE_WITH_SCHEMA);
  }
};
```

Comment: If you are using Postgres 13 or later, you don't need the extension. [gen_random_uuid()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) is built-in

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried. This worked! ʘ‿ʘ

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL vs13 and higher natively supports `gen_random_uuid()`

> `gen_random_uuid () → uuid`
>
> This function returns a version 4 (random) UUID. This is the most commonly used type of UUID and is appropriate for most applications.